# Show an alert from a Firefox extension when a browser window opens

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to make a very simple Firefox extension. I need it to show an alert box when the Firefox window opens. The message doesn't show up when I open the window but it does when I reload all chrome (through the Extensions Developer Add-On).

My overlay file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://adTest/content/alert.js" />
</overlay>
```

My script file:

```
alert("HI!");
```

My chrome.manifest file:

```
content adTest content/ contentaccessible=yes
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://adTest/content/adTestOverlay.xul
```

I'm pretty sure the rest of the code is correct because I've added XUL elements for testing purposes and everything worked apart from the alert box.

Comment: Can you put content of "chrome.manifest" here?

Comment: I have added chrome.manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot display `alert()`s before the browser window is actually loaded and displayed, because the alert dialog has to have a fully-initialized and visible parent window.
Your overlay script will however be run during the load/initialization already...

The Browser Console should show an error saying `NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Cannot call openModalWindow on a hidden window` (but turns out, only when `alert` is called from within the `load` event handler).

So, first wait for the `load` event and then give the event loop a chance to actually show the window, e.g.

```
addEventListener("load", function() {
    setTimeout(function() { alert("something"); }, 0);
});
```

Comment: It seems like that's the problem. I tried initialising variables instead of alert() and everything worked fine. However, the browser console showed nothing.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tested your solution to a bigger project of mine with the same problem. From what I understand, this problem(and your solution) aplies to XPCOM interfaces.

Comment: XPCOM components (and JS code modules, and JS Sandboxes incl. `bootstrap.js` or SDK `main.js`) do not have a window. As such you cannot call `alert()` -> `window.alert()` from such things (You may go through nsIPrompter directly, or use another work around, but this is getting off-topic now)

Answer (score 1):

Can also do:

```
Services.prompt.alert(null, 'title of alert', 'alert msg');
```

In place of `null` you can supply `window` and that will make that window modal and unselectable while that alert is showing (just like normal alert)